# positional argument follows keyword argument when trying to use () brackets to assign variable inline

Tags: python, php

I am trying to understand assignment in Python based off a PHP background but I keep getting `positional argument follows keyword argument`.

```
class Process:
    def revcline(self):
        return self
    def test(self):
        return [b"0xff"]

def process(arg):
    return Process()

rip = int(p = process("test").revcline().test()[-1].decode(), 16)

print(rip)
```

I tried to wrap brackets around the assignment to say "do this first":

```
rip = int((p = process("test")).revcline()....., 16)
```

But then it gives me: `invalid syntax`.

In PHP, this works...:

```
($p = process('test'))->revcline()...
```

Is this possible to replicate in Python or do I need to declare `p` outside the expression? ie:

```
p   = process("test")
rip = int(p.revcline().test()[-1].decode(), 16)
```

Comment: `=` is part of the *assignment statement*, it cannot be used as an expression. However, the so-called "walrus operator", `:=` was added to recent python versions

Comment: in short it means that You can do this: `rip = int(p := process("test").revcline().test()[-1].decode(), 16)`